# Output console with maven and netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, console, dependencies

i have a trouble with a project with maven.
If I build the project with dependencies on Netbeans and then click on Run, it gaves me a wrong output of my program.
But if I build it with the linux consol (with mvn assembly:assembly) and then :

> java -jar target/jar-with-dependencies.jar

it gaves me the good answer on the console output..

Is there a configuration in Netbeans to do?
Thanks..

Comment: What is the output your getting and what is the output your expecting?

Comment: What is the best way to build and test a maven project with Netbeans? and how to build it and test it without it and to have the same results?

Comment: Without what, Maven? If it's a maven project have you built the application with the clean install goals?